# How to use flexible layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have this page on my angular project: [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drCod.png), but I didn't get the result I want.
I used bootstrap to make it responsive using columns and rows. How can I fix my code to get a responsive frame?

When the screen gets smaller, the blocks shoould be one under another. Besides a responsive and flexible layout I hope you can help me.
This my html code :

```css
.red {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.green {
  height: 30%;
  margin: 1%;
  background-color: green;
}

.bleu {
  background-color: blue;
}

.block {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 red ">
    sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10  bleu">
    <h1> overview </h1>
    <div class=" row green"> block </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col block">
        block1
      </div>
      <div class="col block ">
        block2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to make the ui with flex you have to "Think of it in box forms" with the total container as one box then check its children so, here there is the sidebar and the other content(which takes the rest of the space). Now think about what is the rest and so on..

Comment: imp css property to use will be `flex`, `display:flex`, and its horizontal and vertical align prop as well as the `flex-direction`, rest you can code it Maybe `gap` also for the in-between spaces.

Comment: As @innocent has suggested, you should check out display: flex CSS property as it seems to be the best solution for your problem. Another thing you may need are media queries that allow you to create different styles for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

using with `flex` & `@media screen`

```css
.container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .sidebar {
            width: 16.6%;
            background-color: aqua;
        }
        .content {
            width: 83.3%;
        }
        
        .header {
            background-color: coral;
        }

        .row {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .col {
            background-color: burlywood;
            width: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {       
            .container {
                flex-direction: column;  
            }
            .sidebar {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .content {
                width: 100%;
            }
        
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
          sidebar
        </div>
        <div class="content bleu">
            <h1 class="header"> overview </h1>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col block">
              block1
            </div>
            <div class="col block ">
              block2
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code